# Which quantum reality will be seen in a future Earth

Tags: space-time, multiverse, quantum-mechanics

If we orbit near a black hole to travel to future and come back to Earth, which of the quantum realities will be observed in the future Earth?

My question is regarding many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics according to which multiple alternate futures are possible https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'quantum reality'. I don't think this term is defined in any way.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I think the question goals some expected experimental result of a hypotetical GR+QM mixing scenario.

Comment: @peterh Or a documentary starring Michio 'Timetravel ' Kaku. Neither is science unfortunately.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Kaku is one of the best reputated physicists in the USA. What he does *is science*. But there is a long, long problem on the SE here, somehow topological extensions of the GR, and anything related to them (wormhole, alcubierre drive and so on), are generally disliked. But it is a popular topic, the SE is also a popular scientific site, and explaining the current best versions of the science to the common people, I can't see any bad in it (and I can't see why would it be off-topic). It may be off-topic because it is essentially a GR question in astronomical clothes.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I think the question could be somehow refactored, instead of using the word "quantum reality", it should use the word "QM state". But I am not sure, how would it look better.

Comment: @peterh: Well, we won't know until OP clarifies his question. You think he's asking science, I think he's asking quantum healing, so we have to look to OP.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Well, yes. I admit it is unclear. On "quantum reality" he may think on the Star Trek, [here](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Quantum_reality).

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape As far I know, Star Trek was in the beginning highly unpopular in scientist circles because of the terrible bubble speech. But later they understood, that even if it popularizes scientific-looking crap, it popularizes also the real science, too. I think, we on the SE should think the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them.

If you sit on Earth then (in the many worlds interpretation) each quantum mechanical observation creates multiple universes, and there is a copy of "you" in each one. So if I were to ask, which universe will I be in tomorrow, the answer is "all of them" (except the ones in which I die)

If I go into space, float around and come back I will come back in all of the universes. Because I have been moving (relative to Earth) there will be a slight clock discrepancy in all the universes.

If I go into space, orbit a black hole, then come back. I will come back in all the universes (except for the ones that I die in). There will be a large discrepancy in clock time but that is irrelevant. I've not done any movie time-travel. It's just that my watch doesn't match the clocks on Earth.

In the Copenhagen interpretation you come back in the one universe (with a certain probability that is close to 1). As the mathematics is identical, there is no experiment that can distinguish between different interpretations of QM.